# Java daemon process performance testing not getting consistent results

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection, performance-testing, cpu, cpu-usage

I am trying to test cpu consumption of an agent / daemon process written in Java. To avoid getting skewed by garbage collection, I keep trying longer periods for each profiling run. In the beginning I tried 15 minutes, then later arrived at 2 hours. Yet I just found out that, even with 2 hour runs, I can get very inconsistent results. - One run of 2 hours gave me cpu of 6%, another of 2 hours gave me cpu of 12%.

Any suggestions to get consistent results?

Answer (score 2):

Are you controlling for CPU frequency?  If there isn't much work to do, the OS (or CPU itself) might reduce the clock frequency to save power.  With an aggressive power-management strategy, the CPU will always run at max when it's running at all, so looking CPU% can be meaningful.

On Linux on a Skylake or later CPU, you might set the EPP for each core to `performance`, to get it to run at max speed whenever it's running at all.

```
sudo sh -c 'for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy[0-9]*/energy_performance_preference;do echo performance > "$i";done'
```

---

Otherwise maybe measure in core clock cycles (like Linux `perf stat java ...`) instead of CPU %, or at least look at average clock speed while it was running.  (Lower clock speed relative to DRAM can skew things, since a cache miss stall for fewer cycles.)

Comment: Thank you! I don't see anything under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/`. My cpu is under aarch64 architecture. Does the setting only apply to x86?

Comment: @somenickname: EPP is specific to Intel CPUs, Skylake and later (using the `intel_pstate` power management driver), not just x86-64.  Most systems have some way to adjust the power-management settings to achieve the same end result (running at max CPU frequency whenever it's not asleep), so look for how to do that on whatever system you're using.